# Why filter seems not to have effect on my measure in Table?

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

_Hi, I can't figure out why, when I add  my Values measure in table 2 (versus table 1), it then shows me the ERP calculated values for "IGH" whereas i am not asking for it ? I've tried a lot of things but i must not understand something with filter context...

Thanks for your help !   [Here is my pbix file link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv8GLXZX5OzoR-wFO8?e=UcBo5p)

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Which is table 2 and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: yes: Table 1 and Table 2 are named in my pbix file. I except to see, in table 2, only the values for selected building which is not the case. I've got ERP & IGH values... IS that enough clarifying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
Values = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( VALUES('Plans Comptages'[N° CPT]) ), CROSSFILTER('Plans Comptages'[N° CPT], 'BDD Index'[N°CPT], Both))
```

Comment: This measure works perfectly (233) and only for my ERP building. Thanks !!
I am still looking for the total of  'Plans Comptages'[N° CPT] for the selected building (245), but my wrong measure Values shows the total 245 for IGH as well... Almost done...

Comment: Yes. How could I get the total 245 only for my ERP building ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. Sorry

Comment: Sorry for my explanation. 233 is the result of the values of 'Plans Comptages'[N° CPT] filtered by 'BDD Index'[N°CPT]. How do I get the TOTAL of 'Plans Comptages'[N° CPT] without affecting the table, ie just for the selected building (245) ?

Comment: Does this do what you want? Measure = CALCULATE(  DISTINCTCOUNT('Plans Comptages'[N° CPT] ),  REMOVEFILTERS())

Comment: No, 245 appears for ERP but make IGH re-appear in the table...

Comment: I'm really confused. I think this is probably my last attempt: CALCULATE(  DISTINCTCOUNT('Plans Comptages'[N° CPT] ),    ALLSELECTED(BAT[BAT]))

Comment: If not solved, I'll let someone else have a go and just delete my answer

Comment: Thanks anyway for your time and the quality of your answers. I'll post another question to mark this one solved !

Comment: OK, thank you  :)